# Calling C# method that has await from WinJS

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs

I have an asynchronous method in C# class

```
namespace ImageHolder
{
    public sealed class BlankFilter
    public async Task<InMemoryRandomAccessStream> applyFilter()
    {
        inputStream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
        decoder = await Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(inputStream);

        /* more code */
    }
}
```

I am calling this function from a WinJS class in the following way

```
filter.applyFilter().then(function (memStream) {
            var msStream = MSApp.createStreamFromInputStream("image/jpeg", memStream);
            var imageURL = URL.createObjectURL(msSteam);
            id("imageInput").src = imageURL;

        });
```

However this is not working and Visual Studio complains that the return type should be changed to IAsyncAction. Doing that is also not helping.

So, what is the correct way to call a C# function that has await from WinJS code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinJS cannot call methods which return `Task<T>` - which is what you get with an async/await method. As the error say, you need to change the return type (or create a new, wrapper method) to `IAsyncOperation<T>`. Converting from `Task<T>` to `IAsyncOperation<T>` is simple (call either `AsAsyncOperation` on the resulting task).

This [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/06/14/exposing-net-tasks-as-winrt-asynchronous-operations.aspx) has more information about this issue.

Comment: Thanks Carlos. The blog was really helpful. One thing it may have missed though.. the functions that return async Task<T> must all be internal to the class. WinRT cannot expose them.